# Another "Missing } inserted in align* environment"

Tags: align, missing

I'm sorry because there are already a lot of questions on this site with such a title but no one seems to have the same problem as I have. I'm new to LaTeX and to this forum by the way.
Here is my issue: without the align* environment, I get no errors, but when I want to align all my lines and use align*, I get
"! Missing } inserted.

}
l.154 \end{align*}"

How to align all my "=" then? My code is just below. Thank you in advance for you feedback.

```
\begin{align*}
Ker(\psi) &= \{ (\sigma, e) \in \mathfrak A_{n} \rtimes_{\varphi} \{-1, 1\}, \psi(\sigma, e)=~$id$_{\mathfrak S_{n}} \} \\
          &= \{ (\sigma, e) \in \mathfrak A_{n} \rtimes_{\varphi} \{-1, 1\}, i(\sigma)s(e)=~$id$_{\mathfrak S_{n}} \} \\
          &= \{ (\sigma, e) \in \mathfrak A_{n} \rtimes_{\varphi} \{-1, 1\}, i(\sigma)s(e)=~$id$_{\mathfrak S_{n}} \} \\
          &= \{ (\sigma, e) \in \mathfrak A_{n} \rtimes_{\varphi} \{-1, 1\}, i(\sigma)=~$id$_{\mathfrak S_{n}}~$et$~s(e)=~$id$_{\mathfrak S_{n}} \} \\
          &= \{ ($id$_{\mathfrak A_{n}}, 1) \}
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is twofold: LaTeX giving you an error and the `align` environment not fulfilling your alignment needs.

The cause for the former is the use of `$` characters to encapsulate what seem to be custom operators (`id` and `Ker`, I assume; as pointed out in a previous answer). The solution to this is to declare them as such with the `\DeclareMathOperator` macro; e.g., `\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}` for the `id` operator (as per the same previous answer. Note that this macro is preferred over `\text` and `\mathrm` for operators since these handle letter spacing differently.

Since you have multiple `=` signs on each line, to have them all line up you need to use the `alignat` environment (or, in your case its brother `alignat*`; also from the `amsmath` package). Using your example (with some cleanup done to your formatting to make the TeX more readable):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
\Ker(\psi) &= \{(\sigma,e) \in \mathfrak{A}_n \rtimes_{\varphi} \{-1,1\}, \psi(\sigma,e) &&= \id_{\mathfrak{S}_n}\} \\
           &= \{(\sigma,e) \in \mathfrak{A}_n \rtimes_{\varphi} \{-1,1\}, i(\sigma)s(e)  &&= \id_{\mathfrak{S}_n}\} \\
           &= \{(\sigma,e) \in \mathfrak{A}_n \rtimes_{\varphi} \{-1,1\}, i(\sigma)s(e)  &&= \id_{\mathfrak{S}_n}\} \\
           &= \{(\sigma,e) \in \mathfrak{A}_n \rtimes_{\varphi} \{-1,1\}, i(\sigma)      &&= \id_{\mathfrak{S}_n} \text{et } s(e) &&= \id_{\mathfrak{S}_n}\} \\
           &= \{(\id_{\mathfrak{A}_n}, 1)\}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

This environment takes the number of "columns" as argument (the `{3}`), and the columns are separated using `&` characters. In this case each `=` sign beyond the first is preceded by a double `&&` to achieved the desired effect.

Comment: Regarding the double `&&` (since I didn't really explain it well): Counting the first column as 1, the `alignat` environment makes all odd-numbered columns right-aligned and all even-numbered columns left-aligned. Since the second set of `=` sign should also be left-aligned (like the first set), we insert a "dummy," right-aligned column with the first `&` in the double `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the use of `align` but rather the use of `$ $` inside the `align`

Some alternatives are to use `\text{id}`, `\mathrm{id}`, or (in the preamble) `\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
Ker(\psi) & = \{ (\sigma, e) \in \mathfrak{A}_n \rtimes_\varphi \{-1, 1\}, \psi(\sigma, e)=~\text{id}_{\mathfrak S_{n}} \} \\
          & = \{ (\sigma, e) \in \mathfrak{A}_{n} \rtimes_{\varphi} \{-1, 1\}, i(\sigma)s(e)=~\mathrm{id}_{\mathfrak S_{n}} \} \\
          & = \{ (\sigma, e) \in \mathfrak A_{n} \rtimes_{\varphi} \{-1, 1\}, i(\sigma)s(e)=~\id_{\mathfrak S_{n}} \} \\
          & = \{ (\sigma, e) \in \mathfrak A_{n} \rtimes_{\varphi} \{-1, 1\}, i(\sigma)=~\id_{\mathfrak S_{n}}~\text{et}~s(e)=~\id_{\mathfrak S_{n}} \} \\
          & = \{ (\id_{\mathfrak A_{n}}, 1) \}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, so the use of `$ $` make the  `align` not to work because it is math mode by default? the same can be said about other environments then I guess. Thank you for all the alternatives, it is really instructive !